# How to join these two queries? Figuring out who shares first and last names and how many there are

Tags: mysql

The prompt is: How many voters share the same first and last names? What are these names?
And this is what I have so far. I'm supposed to have them both work in one query, but I have no idea how to get them to go together.

---

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FirstName, LastName) FROM voter_list 
WHERE  (FirstName, LastName)
IN (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM voter_list
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY FirstName, LastName);

SELECT DISTINCT FirstName AS MatchingFirstNames, LastName AS MatchingLastNames FROM voter_list
WHERE ( FirstName, LastName )
IN ( SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM voter_list
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY FirstName, LastName;
```

Comment: Have you check out the keyword 'UNION'?

Comment: Yes, I get error 1222 "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: Can you show an example of the data and the desired result?

Comment: It's not clear how you'd display this information in one result. The answer to the first question is just one row, the answer to the second question is a row for each shared name.

Comment: It's supposed to look like this:
`FirstName ---- LastName ---- NumberOfVotersWithSameNames`
`Bill |             Gates               |     569`
`Steve  |            Jobs            |   *BLANK*`
`Etc.    |      Etc.              |  *BLANK*``

Comment: I'm not sure. This is just how the teacher asked the question and said everything can be done in one query

Comment: You only have 3 columns there. Where is the column for the total number of voters with the same last names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the names of that belong to more than one voter, along with the count of voters for each first/last name?

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM voter_list
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

How many total voters share the same first and last name?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName 
    FROM voter_list
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) x
```

Comment: The second query isn't a count of voters, it's the count of shared names.

Comment: I need to figure out the firstname and lastname of the voters that show up more than once. So for example if Bill Gates appeared multiple times, I'd need to return a row with just the name Bill gates once. Also in this query I need to count the total number of people with the same name. So you're second query works fine, but it all needs to be under one query.

Comment: @HelpMePLZ132 The first query returns the number of Bill Gates duplicates.

Comment: I'm just gonna go with this answer and assume it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross join between the two queries.

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.Total
FROM (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName
    FROM voter_list
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM voter_list v1
    JOIN (
        SELECT FirstName, LastName
        FROM voter_list
        GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS v2 ON v1.FirstName = v2.FirstName AND v1.LastName = v2.LastName
) AS t2
```

`t1` returns the shared names, and `t2` returns the total number of voters with those shared names. The total will be shown on every row of the result.